# How to test ADOConnection ConnectionString before connecting to SQL Server database in Delphi 10.2

Tags: sql-server, delphi, adoconnection

I am working on an application on Delphi 10.2, And it connects to a SQL Server 2014 database. What can I do to test the connection with the database having the connection string before the application starts?

I have used `ADoconnection` as an interface to connect to the aforementioned database, did some coding with try-catch or try-except to rule out the unwanted SQL Server errors, and using a gauge Bar to indicate the advancement of my start procedure (which progresses with query activation and form creation).

So when the connection string is not ok, I will get an error of

> Login failed for user 'admin98'

(admin98 is the name of the SQL Server user); and when the connection string is ok, the gauge bar progresses and in the halfway through I have again the same error.

NOTE: I used `freeInstance` or `NewInstance` or other things like that but it didn't work.

This is the function that connects to the database and catches errors if encounters

```
function DBConnect: Boolean;
var
 conStr : string;
begin
 conStr:= 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin'+Fstart_.year_combobox.Text+';PassWord=000;Initial Catalog=student'+Fstart_.year_combobox.Text+';Data Source='+Fstart_.StringTemp+';';
 DataModule1.ADOConnection1.Close;
 DataModule1.ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:= conStr;
 DataModule1.ADOConnection1.LoginPrompt:= False;
 if (NOT DataModule1.ADOConnection1.Connected) then
  begin
   try
    DataModule1.ADOConnection1.Open;
    Result:= True;
   Except on E:Exception do
    begin
    if e.Message = 'Login failed for user '+chr(39)+'admin'+Fstart_.year_combobox.Text+chr(39) then
     //showmessage
    if e.Message = '[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied' then
     //showmessage
     DataModule1.ADOConnection1.Close;
     DataModule1.ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:= '';
     Result:= False;
    end;
   end;
  end;
end;
```

The thing is that it has to work and I shouldn't restart the application so I need to either test before connection or reset the whole connection.

I expect the successful connection but I get the error again even when I change the combo box value and I know that the user exists in SQL Server

Comment: What can work in these circumstancies is to run a background thread which attempts to connect to the server every few seconds.  If it has recently failed several times in succession you can notify the user before attempting to connect using your ADOConnection1.

Comment: @MartynA 
Thank you for Answering, but the multithreading thing is a bit too hard for me right now
and based on other parts of the application i will have many problems later on

Comment: Reading it again and again, I have trouble understanding your question. You mention error messages, which can't be from this code, because it swallows all. You mention NewInstance and FreeInstance, which you shouldn't call anyway, but which are not in this code... Having the error twice suggests you try to connect twice, also not in this code. All in all, it sounds like the error is in the flow of the application start-up and the use of this procedure. Could you add a bit more code to the question to try to describe how that start-up routine works?

Comment: @GolezTrol
Sure I am sorry because of that.
the code is very function base so it is hard to add I will 
explain it to:
consider the user runs the application and wants to connect to the database, if they select a value in combo box and hit "enter" the connection string will be created in the function above and if the value is worng the error will prompt 
and the user has to change the value of combo box into a proper one 
then it works but in the midway again the error occurs with the last combo box value. but the connection string is updated 
so who can I reset the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Answer worked for me and I found out that I need 5 seconds of `sleep`
to get the thread out of RAM

```
function DBConnect: Boolean;
var
 conStr : string;
begin
 ini:= TMemIniFile.Create(GetCurrentDir + '\Settings.ini');
 Fstart_.StringTemp:= ini.ReadString('Server Directory', 'Server Name', KeyFileString);
 Application.CreateForm(TDataModule1, DataModule1);
 DataModule1.ADOConnection1.Close;
 conStr:= 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin'+Fstart_.year_combobox.Text+';PassWord=123;Initial Catalog=darman'+Fstart_.year_combobox.Text+';Data Source='+Fstart_.StringTemp+';';
 DataModule1.ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:= conStr;
 DataModule1.ADOConnection1.LoginPrompt:= False;
 try
  DataModule1.ADOConnection1.Open;
  Result:= True;
 Except on E:Exception do
  begin
   if e.Message = 'Login failed for user '+chr(39)+'admin'+Fstart_.year_combobox.Text+chr(39) then
     // Showmessage 
    [mbOK],0);
   if e.Message = '[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied' then
    // ShowMessage
   DataModule1.ADOConnection1.Close;
   DataModule1.Destroy;
   Sleep(5000);
  end;
 end;
end;
```